# GCP - how to deploy template using python?

Tags: python, deployment, google-cloud-platform, devops

I want to automate the creation of services in GCP using template defined in python/jinja like in IaaC methods.
But the automation where I want to run all process is some python app.

I searched but I did not find any library on python which will be able to deploy GCP template.

Does anyone know how to automate building services in GCP using python and templates?

Comment: What are you looking for? A platform where to run your Python/jinja script, but without building this platform?

Comment: I want to run python/jinja template from Python app

Comment: You mean to reuse python/jinja template defined in [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-template)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I want to run python my_deplo_app.py which will be deplo python/jinja template. Is it possible, to do that?

Comment: Hi, maybe [app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) could be what you are looking for, you could deploy your app and it could scale seamlessly without having to worry about managing the underlying infrastructure. You can run [jinja](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/generating-dynamic-content-templates) as well

Comment: @criss, the reason of why I asked you is because I didn't understand your troubles. Cloud Run or App Engine can host your app without any problem. Package your web application as required and enjoy! If you need more helps, provide more details on the issues that you encounter!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Client library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide) for python